# Evaluation control with TagSet

Tags: evaluation

Suppose I have a property associated with two functions using `TagSet`:

```
f1 /: type[f1[n_][x_]] := n
f2 /: type[f2[n_, m_][x_]] := m
```

But the function are related by

```
f2[n_, m_] := f1[n]
```

In other words, I use a second argument in `f2` to distinguish the property differences.

Now if we do

```
type[f2[1, 2][x]]
(* 1 *)
```

we get `1` instead of `2`. this is because `f2[1,2]` get evaluated into `f1[1]`. We can fix this by setting the attribute of type:

```
SetAttributes[type, HoldAll]
```

and now it behaves as what we desire

```
type[f2[1, 2][x]]
(* 2 *)
```

However, think about the situation that `f2` is some very long expression with many arguments, and instead of writing the long expression every time, I would like to assign it to a short variable for connivence:

```
myf := f2[1,2]
```

But now we are not be able to get the type correctly:

```
type[myf[x]]
type[Evaluate@myf[x]]
(* type[myf[x]] *)
(* 1 *)
```

So how should I deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a question of organizing the definitions differently. If I understand the goal of `type` correctly, it seems redundant to define it based on a pattern that includes the second argument. Instead, you should just define `type` using `TagSet` by giving only the first argument pattern on which the type actually depends. Then you can reserve the pattern `[x]` for when you really want to define the *functional dependence on* `x`, as you do in the identification of `f2` with `f1`:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]

f1 /: type[f1[n_]] := n
f2 /: type[f2[n_, m_]] := m

f2[n_, m_][x_] := f1[n][x]

type[f1[1]]

(* ==> 1 *)

type[f2[1, 2]]

(* ==> 2 *)

myf := f2[1, 2]

type[myf]

(* ==> 2 *)
```

Now there are no more conflicts. I think it's cleaner this way.

Answer (score 3):

If the application permits, one way might be to add a third definition to `type`:

```
type[x_] := type[Evaluate@Block[{f1, f2}, x]]
```

By temporarily blocking the definitions of `f1` and `f2`, expressions like `myf` can evaluate to their constituent parts involving those symbols.  We then apply `type` to the result, and the upvalues on `f1` and `f2` can once again take effect:

```
type[f1[1][x]]
(* 1 *)

type[f2[1, 2][x]]
(* 2 *)

type[myf[x]]
(* 2 *)
```

As defined, `type` will loop indefinitely should it ever be applied to an expression that is completely independent of `f1` and `f2`:

```
type[z]
(* $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded. >> *)
```

To guard against this possibility, we make sure that the last definition only takes effect if the evaluation of its argument actually resulted in a change:

```
ClearAll[type]
SetAttributes[type, HoldAll]
f1 /: type[f1[n_][x_]] := n
f2 /: type[f2[n_, m_][x_]] := m
(* here is the change: *)
type[x_] := With[{e = Block[{f1, f2}, x]}, type[e] /; Hold[e] =!= Hold[x]]
```

Now:

```
type[f1[1][x]]
(* 1 *)

type[f2[1, 2][x]]
(* 2 *)

type[myf[x]]
(* 2 *)

type[z]
(* type[z] *)

type[11 + 22]
(* type[33] *)
```

This strategy might not be suitable if `f1` and `f2` are themselves `HoldAll` because `Block` will temporarily disable that attribute as well, leading to evaluation leaks.  It would also be unsuitable if the application will not tolerate the partial evaluation of expressions such as we see in the last example above.

Comment: +1. I am using very similar techniques in such cases, too.

Comment: That's impressive for me! Thanks for sharing the knowledge, I can imaging using it a lot in the future. I wish I could accept both answers, but Jens's answer seems to be slightly simpler for me.